# I am trying to import dash

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to import dash library but when I do

```
pip install dash==0.26.5
```

I get the following message:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jinja2>=2.10 (from Flask>=0.12->dash) (from versions: 2.7.3, 2.8) No matching distribution found for Jinja2>=2.10 (from Flask>=0.12->dash)`

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not have to specify the version when installing a package via `pip`, it gets the latest automatically :

```
pip install dash
```

The error comes from the fact that you are using some outdated pip packages. And the latest version of `dash`, that is `0.26.5`, is not compatible with some of them and creates conflicts when trying to install.

EDIT : as [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)  commented it, to upgrade neccessary packages at installation, use `--upgrade`:

```
pip install --upgrade dash
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade dash` upgrades all necessary packages.